# Prove scalar products are invariant under all orthogonal transormation

Tags: matrices, transformation, matrix-equations, invariant-theory

I wondering how to prove: That scalar products are invariant under all orthogonal transformation:

$<\!x, y\!>\; =\;<\!Qx, Qy\!>$

which holds for all vector $x$,$y \in \Re^n$ and all matrices $Q \in \Re^{n\times n}$ that are orthogonal.

Comment: What have you tried? All you need is two definitions: the standard scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (given by $\langle x, y\rangle = x^{T}y$) and orthogonality of a matrix (in this case meaning that $Q^T Q = I$).

Answer (score 3):

$<x,y>=x^t y$

$<Qx,Qy>=x^tQ^tQy$

Since $Q$ is orthogonal then $Q^tQ=I$ and hence the scalar product remains invariant